# Navigation PushModalAsync not working inside of event inside ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list view with item template formed of several elements, one of them is a frame with `TapGestureRecognizer` added to it as the following example:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Margin="10,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- Other Element -->

                    <Frame x:Name="SampleFrame" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

```cs
public TVEntryItem()
{
    InitializeComponent();
            
    var TapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    TapGesture.Tapped += TapGesture_Tapped;
    SampleFrame.GestureRecognizers.Add(TapGesture);
}

private void TapGesture_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DetailedView());
}
```

Now when I tap on the frame the event is called indeed and a new instance of `DetailedView` is created -Verified by break point in the `DetailedView` constructor function-, but the page itself is never displayed, and the break point inside the `DetailedView` `OnAppearing` is never hit.

What am I missing here ?! Any suggestions ?! Thanks in advance ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Lucas Zhang - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10216982/lucas-zhang-msft)'s answer, I could come up with a solution. As he described, I cannot call navigation service inside a `ViewCell`, so, simply, I called the navigation service from the main page instead.

```cs
private void TapGesture_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DetailedView());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case , the Frame is in a ViewCell , so it will never if you handle it in **ContentPage** directly .

Firstly , make sure that the **MainPage**  of the App is a **NavigationPage**

#### in App.xaml.cs

```
  public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new xxxPage());
    }
```

If you want to add a TapGesture on the frame , you could check the following code .

#### in Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             
             x:Name="Page"  // set the name of contentpage here
             
             x:Class="xxx.xxxPage">
```

```
<Frame  Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Red">

    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>

        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Page}, Path=BindingContext.TapCommand}" />

    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

</Frame>
```

#### in ContentPage

```
 public xxxPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new xxxViewModel(this.Navigation);
    }
```

#### in ViewModel

public class xxxViewModel
{

```
    public ICommand TapCommand { get; private set; }

    INavigation Navigation;

    public MyViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {

        this.Navigation = navigation;

      

        TapCommand = new Command(()=> {

            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1());

        });

       // other code ,like setting itemsource of listview

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the example I showed above is a very simple reference of a bigger thing which makes it pretty difficult to apply your method, however using what you said I could come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new DetailedView()));
```